# mysql routines and session variables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I don't have a great deal of programming experience.
With reference to the latest version of XAMPP/MySQL, is one supposed to be able to use session variables in MySQL routines? I am using phpMyAdmin so the following represents the full code as entered.

My routine is like this: -

```
BEGIN
    SELECT @x;
END
```

but when I execute

```
SET @x:= 6;
CALL routine;
```

nothing is returned.

If my routine is like this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE x INT; 
    SET x := 5;
    SELECT x;
END
```

and I execute `CALL routine;`

I am returned a table with x and 5 below it.

At other times routines seem to have the effect of either returning session variables as NULL or of returning an unmodified value of @x which the routine is supposed to have modified. I have been unable to find anything on the web to explain this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show full code. What tool/language do you use?

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin so the full code is as entered.

Comment: *I am returned, `CALL routine`*: did you mean *I'm returned 6*?

Comment: No, the interface tells me that I have just executed 'CALL routine;', but there are no results from the execution.

Comment: I'm not sure about the phpmyadmin. If you can access MySQL server, try another tool, e.g. - MySQL command line console; the result data set should be in both cases.

Comment: if you need the routine to change variables **define the input parameters as out or as inout**.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly for me :)
If it does not work for you is because phpMyAdmin is using a different connection for each request (and you, sir, are executing the commands one by one). Execute them all at once :)

```
drop procedure if exists routine_test;
delimiter //
create procedure routine_test ()
begin
    set @var := @var + 1;
    select 'inside routine', @var;
end;
// delimiter ; 


# now execute all these statements at same time
# executing them one by one, might make phpmyadmin use different connections

set @var = 1;
call routine_test();
call routine_test();
call routine_test();
select 'outside routine', @var;
```

If it does not work, it is phpmyadmin that starts a new connection for each time you click execute (which is the way php handles connections). **This is, the connection is closed after the page is sent to the browser of the user, and, the session is over and the variable is cleaned from MySQL memory**.

Comment: Firstly, I was executing SET @x:= 6; and CALL routine; at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, but: - Firstly, I was executing 'SET @x:= 6;' and 'CALL routine;' at the same time. Secondly, when I try to create your procedure an alert asks me if I really want to 'drop procedure if exists'. I click 'yes', but no 'routine_test' procedure is created. Thirdly, when I try to execute your 'call routine' code I am told 'excel_omp.routine_test' doesn't exist. (What is 'excel.omp', by the way?) Finally, to overcome this problem I have reinstalled the latest version of XAMPP, but it makes no difference.

Comment: excel_omp, is a test database that i have (that is a the schema/database) name.
I removed the schema name, try it now. With mysql workbench works fine.

Comment: I tried it and it still didn't work - amongst other things I got, '#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'. I changed to mysql workbench and it works fine. I don't have a lot of experience and I have a lot to do, so I think it's probably better to change to mysql workbench simply for a different frame of reference. My thanks to you and to Devart.